# how to disable cursor but show selected text in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to disable the cursor for edit text and but show selected text from a color. but when I off cursor, the selected color of text also not visible.

here is my code for edit text.

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_below="@id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:padding="@dimen/padding_maintextview" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="23dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:inputType="none"
            android:padding="@dimen/padding_maintextview"
            android:text="@string/text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

and another issue is although I disable input type when I select word, the keyboard pop up. 
I use sdk min 8 and max 15

please help me to sove this.

thanks.

Comment: please not that i have added  tvchange12.setKeyListener(null); but keyboard pop up

Answer (score 0):

Add the Following Attribute in Edittext

```
 android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

> Then You will get the cursor when you selected yout text. The code is
>   as follows

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_below="@id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:padding="@dimen/padding_maintextview" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="23dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:inputType="none"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:padding="@dimen/padding_maintextview"
            android:text="@string/text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: android:focusableInTouchMode="false" will diable displaying selecting text.

Comment: "Then You will get the cursor when you selected yout text." to do that you have to set above property true.

Comment: You want to disable cursor but you need focus on selected edittext is it you want

Comment: i want to disable cursor but if I want to select text to copy then I should be able to focus on the text and copy the selected text. I dont want to see the keyboard too.

Comment: you can use the above which i mentioned in the above for gaining the focus when you want to edit it.And regarding the keyboard mention the android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" in the manifest file.

Comment: android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" is added but still it comes

Comment: you can android:focusableInTouchMode="false" check with the help of this it is working fine for me.